# Who is Shri Ram?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama

Who is Lord Rama? **Is he the avatar of Lord Vishnu or the supreme lord of the universe** above even Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh?

Comment: rama = avatar of vishnu = vishnu who has come from vaikunta to earth = supreme lord of universe. they are all one and same being.

Answer (score 3):

सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।

First get clear that there is no difference between Avatār and Avatāri, the same supreme Brahmān reveales on earth or in different Lokā in numerous forms. As पूर्णमद: पूर्णमिदं पूर्णात् concept always apply.

Coming to the first question, who is Śrī Rāma?

Well only Siya Ju Sarkār and Sakīs of Śrī Raghavā like Charushila Ju and Chandrakala Ju can give you the best answer

But this servent will try it's best to reveal the true form of Śrī Rāma in front of you.

Śrī Rāma is the one who appears on earth as an Avatār of Śrī Hāri Vīshnu and some times he comes directly from Saket. When Śrī Hāri Vīshnu takes Śrī Rāma Avatār than his companions are Lakshmāna (Anānt Shësh Nāag), Bharata (Sudãrshan Chakrā) and Shātrughna (Shānkh).

But when Paratpar Par-Brahmā the lord who resides in Sāket appears than the chronology is different, than,

वैकुण्ठेशस्तु भरतः क्षीराब्धीशस्तु लक्ष्मणः ।
शत्रुघ्नस्तु स्वयं भूमा रामसेवार्थमागताः।।

(Nārad Panchratra Brihād Brahmā Samhitā)

Śrī Bhārat who is lord of Vāikuntha, Śrī Lakshmān who resides in Sheer Sagar (क्षीर सागर) and Śrī Shātrughna who is swayam Bhumā Purushā, all of them incarnated with him to serve Śrī Rāma.

Around same question was also asked by Śrī Hanumān ji in Kishkindha Kand,

मृदुल मनोहर सुंदर गाता। सहत दुसह बन आतप बाता॥

की तुम्ह तीनि देव महँ कोऊ। नर नारायन की तुम्ह दोऊ।।

Your beautiful, soft limbs are the destroyer of the mind and you are enduring the sorrowful sun and wind of the forest. Are you one of the three gods or are you both Nara and Narayana.

Again in next doha

जग कारन तारन भव भंजन धरनी भार।
की तुम्ह अखिल भुवन पति लीन्ह मनुज अवतार॥

Or else You are the Lord Himself (of Sāket), the root cause of the world and the master of all the planets, who incarnated in human form to take people across the ocean of material existence and to destroy the burden of the earth.

And Śrī Rāma is the Eternal husband of Srímati Sitā Maharani and appears as a son of King Dashārath and Queen Kaushālya.

Here are few virtues of Śrī Rāma,

स हि रूपोपपन्नश्च वीर्यवाननसूयकः ।

मां नमः भूमावनुपमस्सूनुः गुणैर्दशरथोपमः ॥

(Valmiki Ramayan 2-1-9)

"In his Rupa, Lavanya, Saundarya (beauty, elegance and charm etc), Śrī Rāma is incomparable, He is a hero of valor and without envy (towards anyone). By virtues, he was like Maharaj Dasarātha. In this way, Śrī Rāma was verily an incomparable son on the earth."

स च नित्यं प्रशान्तात्मा मृदुपूर्वं तु भाषते ।

उच्यमानोऽपि परुषं नोत्तरं प्रतिपद्यते ।।

(Valmiki Ramayan 2-1-10)

That Rāma is always peaceful in mind and speaks softly and sweetly (does not speak harsh or rude words even in laughs). He does not react to the hard words spoken by others.

कथंचिदुपकारेण कृतेनै केन तुष्यति ।

न स्मरत्यपकाराणां शतमप्यात्मवत्तया ॥

(Valmiki Ramayan 2-1-11)

That Rama, because of his good bent of mind, feels glad even by whatever way a good or little thing is done to him. He does not remember any number of bad things or offenses done to him.

Śrī Rāma does not think or remember any number of faults or mistakes or bad things done to him by others, he is the sweetest Lord.

अप्रधृष्यश्च संग्रामे क्रुद्धैरपि सुरासुरैः ।

अनसूर्यो जितक्रोधो न दृप्तो न च मत्सरी ।

न चावमन्ता भूतानां न च कालवशानुगः ॥

(Valmiki Ramayan 2-1-31)

"Even enraged gods as well as demons could not contain or defeat Shri Rama in the battle*. Shri Rama is free from jealousy. He is conquered anger. He has no arrogance and envy. He had not humiliated any living being. Kaala (time) could not control him, He remains always same in his own transcendental virtues (free from anger, envy, undefeated, soft and sweet spoken, always righteous, noble, gentle etc) and qualities (ever Youthful, attractive and charming etc)."

*This is also indicated in Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas,

संकर सहस बिष्नु अज तोही।

सकहिं न राखि राम कर द्रोही॥

Śrī Hanumān said; O Ravaña, I swear that even thousands of Vishnu and thousands of Shankar cannot protect the one who is enemy of Śrī Rāma.

वैहारिकाणां शिल्पानां विज्ञातार्थविभागवित् ।

आरोहे विनये चैव युक्तोवारणवाजिनाम् ।।

(Valmiki Ramayan 2-1-28)

For Vihar-Kreeda-Prayojana (disporting and delighting during Vihaar-kreeda), Shri Rama knows the arts of Music, and dance. He also knows painting, playing the instruments, etc. He knows how to distribute the wealth. He is efficient in riding and taming of elephants and horses etc.

गान्धर्वे च भुवि श्रेष्ठो बभूव भरताग्रजः ।

(vālmīki rāmāyaṇa 2.2.35)

Shri Rama is best in the world in the arts of music and dance.

Maharshi Vālmiki says in Śrī Rāmāyaṇa, Śrī Rāma is the Kāma-vardhanah (means mere a sight of whom infuses love towards him in everyone, not in just women, but even among men, from animals even to ordinary creepers- plants-trees and rivers, all feel a strong attraction and love towards him in Shringaar i.e. romance, such Kaam- vardhanah he is). That's Rāmcharit Mānas says Kāam Köti Chhābi Syām Sarirā, One doesn't need to chant a separate Kāma-mantra for Śrī Rāma, as the name 'Rāma' itself means the one who is foremost among all those who delight others (rāmō ramayatām śrēṣṭhaḥ) [Śrīmad Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa 2.53.1]; 'Rāma' means the one who gives bliss; And bliss (ananda) is the most subtle and essence of all. Śrī Rāma is the only one in whole cosmos who can delight (give bliss to) 'Śrī Ji (Sītā Ji), none else.

In Valmiki Ramayana, the story of Śrī Rāma starts from the time when he is around 13 years old. Valmiki intentionally skipped initial 12 years of leela of Bhagavan Śrī Rāma in greater good of society, which is predominantly his dev-leela, unrestrained display of his complete divinity. (Just like Ved-Vyasa skipped childhood pastimes of Śrī Krishna in Mahabharata, yet His initial 12 years Madhurya pastimes in Vrindavan is disclosed in Bhagavatam only.) Similarly, childhood-leela of Śrī Rāma is revealed in many Ramayana-s mainly Śrīmad Bhüshundí Ramayan, Satyopakhyan etc, He does many divine- pastimes in the villages of many divine forests on the bank of river Sarayu. Before his marriage, he did many divine-pastimes, He did many Rāsa dance with many Gop-kanya-s (gopi-s), deva-kanyas, Gandharva-Kanya-s etc on the bank of river Sarayu. He was the one who did Rāsa-dance first time in Vrindāvan on bank of River Yamuna, this was the reason when BrahmA appears in Yuddha-Kanda before him after the elimination of Ravana, He eulogized Śrī Rāma as the one who is worshiped by Gopika-s in Vrindavan in Adhyatm-Ramayana.

Now coming to second question that is he a avatar of Vishnu or supreme lord even above Brahma Vishnu and Shiva?

As this servent quoted earlier that Śrī Rāma is both Avatari and Avatar and their is no difference between them. But in Śrī Samprāday Śrī Rāma is worshipped as an Avatāri from whom everything has emerged out like Brahmā, Vishnu even Maha Vishnu, Shiva, Krishna, Narsimha etc.

यस्यांशेन एव ब्रह्म विष्णु महेश्वरा अपि जाता महाविष्णुर्य्यस्य दिव्यगुणाश्च ।

स एव कार्यकारणयोः परः परमपुरुषो रामो दाशरथिर्वभुव॥

Atharvavedā Shrüti Vedsaropanishad

Whose Ansh are Brahma Visnu and Mahesvara, Whose divine Guna is Mahavisnu, The only one who is the cause of all causes, The one who is higher than the highest, such is Śrī Rāma, the son of Dasratha. (Approx same shloka is also found in Vashisht Samhita Ch. 26 and Samved Sudarshan Samhita 1–5.)

As Śrī Rāma himself says;

योऽपि नारायणोऽनन्तो लोकानां प्रभवाव्ययः ।
ममैव परमा मूर्तिः करोति परिपालनम्॥

(श्रीमद्रामायणे वाल्मीकीये अद्भुतोत्तरकाण्डे भगवद्धनूमत्संवादो नाम चतुर्दशः सर्गः)

The Lord of the infinite worlds, who is inseparable Nāräyan, is my supreme form and maintains the universe.

Vīshnu, Narayan, Krishna, Narsimha, Varah etc all other Gods and Demi Gods are only the manifestation Śrī Rāma and Śrī Rāma is Paratpar.

एतेषु चैव सर्वेषु तत्त्वं च ब्रह्म तारकम् ।
राम एव परं ब्रह्म राम एव परं तपः ।।
राम एव परं तत्त्वं श्रीरामो ब्रह्म तारकम् ।।
वायुत्रेणोक्तास्ते योगीन्द्रा ऋषयो विष्णुभक्ता हनूमन्तं पप्रच्छुः रामस्याङ्गानि नो ब्रूहीति ।
वायुपुत्रं विघ्नेशं वाणीं दुर्गां क्षेत्रपालकं सूर्यं चन्द्रं नारायणं नारसिंहं वायुदेवं वाराहं तत्सर्वान्त्समात्रान्त्सीतं लक्ष्मणं शत्रुघ्नं भरतं विभीषणं सुग्रीवमङ्गदं जाम्बवन्तं प्रणवमेतानि रामस्याङ्गानि जानीथाः ।

(Yajurvedā Shrüti RāmRahāshyopanishād)

In all the scriptures like Vedās, the supreme principle is 'Tāraka Rāma' in the form of Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is the Supreme Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is the supreme form. Śrī Rāma is the Supreme Being. Śrī Rāma is Tarakabrahma. Hanumān Ji preached to the devotee of Śrī Hāri Vīshnu and other Rishis "I myself, Śrī Ganēshā, Goddess Saraswati, Goddess Durgā, All the Guardian (Khetra Pāl), Sun (Suryā), Moon, Lord Śrī Hāri Nāräyana, Lord Naräsimha, Lord Vāsudev (Śrī Krishnā), Lord Vāraha etc. all are the mere parts of Lord Śrī Rāma. Lakshmāna, Shātrughna, Bharata, Vibhishana, Sugriva, Angad, Jambavant and Pranav (Om ॐ) are also mere parts of Lord Śrī Rāma.

Śrī Rāma and his manifestations are also mentioned in Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmayan in Yuddh Kanda in Sarg 117 as said,

भवान् नारायणो देवः श्रीमांश्चाक्रायुधः प्रभुः ।

एकशृङ्गो वराहस्त्वं भूतभव्यसपत्नजित् ।।

'You are Lord Narayana, the omnipotent lord who holds the wheel, the earth-bearer with a beard and the conqueror of past and future enemies of the deities.

Here Brahmā ji is worshipping Śrī Rāma as Visheshya and with Visheshan he equalize Sri Rama with Śrī Hāri Nāräyana, Krishnā. He is telling that O Śrī Rāma you incarnates as Nāräyan who hold chakra, you incarnated as Krishnā and so on.

As said in various other scriptures same as Vedas,

द्विभुजो जानकीजानिस्सदा सर्वत्र एव हि।

भक्तेच्छातः पुनर्जातो वैकुंठे ते चतुर्भुज।।

(Shiv Samhita 5 Patal)

The two-armed Janakivallabh shri ram you are always everywhere. By the will of your devotee, you take 4 handed narayan form in vaikunth.

परं ब्रह्म परं धामं जगतां कारणं परम् ।

नागशय्या शयानं च द्विभुज रघुनंदनम्।।

(Satyopakhyan)

Two armed Shri Raghunandan is the supreme Brahman, supreme abode and is the cause of jagat who rests on bed of serpent.

ततस्तवमसि दुर्धर्षात्रस्माद भावात् सनातनात्।

रक्षार्थ सर्वभुतानाम् विष्णुसं उपजग्मिवान्।।

(Valmiki Ramayan 7.104.9)

Kaal says:- After my prayers, in the beginning of creation, you forsaken your durdharssa form(form that is difficult to be achieved by so me many) the bhava (2 armed Shri Ram) and assumed the form of Vishnu for the sake of protection and sustenance of all living beings.

Why Visheshya and Visheshan?

As said futher their,

लोकानां त्वं परो धर्मो विष्वक्सेनश्चतुर्भुजः

You are the supreme religion of the people. You are Vishvaksena Chaturbhuja. (Vishwaksena, is the commander-in-chief of the army of the Vishnu, additionally serving as a gatekeeper and chamberlain of celestial abode Vaikuntha.)

Now tell me have you seen Śrī Rāma gatekeepering Vāikuntha and fighting in favour of Devatas with four arms?

Not at all, all these Visheshan are been used to show Omnipresence of Śrī Rāma that it's only Śrī Raghunandan who manifests an Nāräyana, Vīshnu, Krishna, Vāraha, Vishvaksena etc.

Infact Śrī Raghavā is,

परान्नाराय गाच्चैव कृष्णात्परतरादपि ।
यो वै परतम श्रीमान् सवै दाशरथि स्वराट् ॥
जय मत्स्याद्यसंख्येयावतारोद्भवकारण । ब्रह्मविष्णुमहेशादिसंसेव्यचरणाम्बुज ।।

(Narad Panchratra Vashistha Samhita)

The one who is beyond Śrī Hāri Nāräyana, who is beyond even Śrī Krishnā, who is the most Paratammamvarat Paramatma, that is Dashrath's son Raghavā. Whose lotus feet are served by Brahma ādi Tridev (Shri Shiva and Shri Vishnu) and Matsya etc, is the reason for many incarnations. Hail to you such Supreme Lord Śrī Raghunandan.

नारायणोपि रामशः शंखचक्रगदाव्जधृक्।

चतुर्भुजस्वरूपेण वैकुण्ठे च प्रकाशते ॥

अवतारा बहवः सति कलाश्चांशविभूतयः।

राम एव परं ब्रह्म सच्चिदानन्दमव्ययम्।।

(Nārad Panchratra Śrī Bhardwaj Samhita)

Śrī Hāri Nārāyana is an incarnation of Śrī Rāma and shines in Vaikunth in the form of four arms with conch, chakra and mace. There are many incarnations of Śrī Rāma differentiating by Kalas, Part, Vibhuti etc. But Śrī Rāma himself is Par-Brahma who is devoid of Maya in his two armed form (human form)

सूर्यस्यापि भवेत्सूर्यो ह्यग्नेरग्नि प्रभोः प्रभुः।

श्रियः श्रीश्च भवेदग्र्या कीर्तिः कीर्त्याः क्षमाक्षमा ।।

दैवतं दैवतानां च भूतानां भूतसत्तमः ।

तस्य के ह्यगुणा देवि वने वाप्यथवा पुरे ॥

(Śrī Valmiki Rāmāyaṇa 2.44.15/16)

"Oh, Kausalya! Rama is the sun of even sun (the illuminator of even sun), He is the fire of even fire, the Narayan (prabhu*) of the Narayan (*here the word prabhu denotes narayan not Devatas, as devata are already mentioned in next shloka) ,(Śrimati Sītā is) the Śrī of Śrī i.e. the Goddess of even Śrī-devi (Lakshmi), the foremost glory of glory, the forbearance of forbearance, the Devata of all Devata, and the foremost being (i.e. the Supreme-being) among all the beings. Indeed, what misfortune could be ever there for such Rama whether he lives in the forest or city?

Śrī Hāri Nāräyana and others are the incarnation of Śrī Rāma as mentioned in Vedas and other scriptures as mentioned above.(many people doubt that if their any Maha-Vishnü word mentioned in Vedas? A big big Yes! Śrī Rāma in Atharvavedā Rāma Tapniye Upnishad has been called as Maha-Vishnü)

Shrimad Valmiki Ramayana is the most authoritative scripture in Vishishtadvaita- Vaishnavism, Brahma himself told 'there is no grain of untruth in it'. When Śrī Rām killed Ravana, then Lord Brahma came and did Stuti of Śrī Rām. He eulogized Shri Ram in various ways, BrahmA mentions Narayana, Krishna, Varaha, Hrishikesa, Vishnu etc as various forms of Shri Rama.

Srímati Sitā Maharani is has also been depicted as Lakshmi as Śrī Lakshmï is an incarnation of Śrī Sītā,

सीता लक्ष्मीर्भवान् विष्णुर्देवः कृष्णः प्रजापतिः ||

(VR- 6.117.28)

O Śrī Rām, Maa Sītā is Goddess Lakshmi (the divine consort of Lord Vishnu), while You are Lord Visnu. You are Lord Krishna.

As also said in Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas,

जासु अंस उपजहिं गुनखानी।

अगनित लच्छि उमा ब्रह्मानी॥

भृकुटि बिलास जासु जग होई।

राम बाम दिसि सीता सोई॥

From whose fraction the innumerable mines of virtues Lakshmi, Parvati and Brahmani (powers of the trinity) are produced and by whose brow the world is created, The same (Swarupa-Shakti of the Lord) Sita is situated on the left side of Rama.

Here one should not get confused with these Visheshan applying for Śrī SitāRāmā. Again telling here Brahmā ji is worshipping Śrī Rāma as Visheshya by using Visheshan for them.

As Maa Lakshmi is non other than Incarnation of Srímati Sitā Maharani as mentioned in Vedās,

Śrī Sītā has been depicted as the Original form of all Shakti in Vedās as shown below,

सा देवी त्रिविधा भवति शक्त्यासना इच्छाशक्तिः क्रियाशक्तिः साक्षाच्छक्तिरिति इच्छाशक्तिस्त्रिविधा भवति श्रीभूमिनीलात्मिका भद्ररूपिणी प्रभावरूपिणी सोमसूर्याग्निरूपा भवति

Athârvavedā Shrüti Sītā Upänīshad

Śrī Sītā is threefold through Her power, namely the power of desire, the power of action, and the power of knowledge. Taking the incarnation of Śrī Devi, Bhudevi, Neeladevi, the one who benefits everyone with her influence, shines in the form of moon, sun and fire.

That's why in Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmayan which is itself Incarnation of Vedās clearly says that Śrī Sītā is even Śrī of Bhagwāti Śrī.

वसुधाया हि वसुधां श्रियः श्रीं भर्तृवत्सलाम् ।
सीतां सर्वानवद्याङ्गीमरण्ये विजने शुभाम् ।।

(Valmiki Ramayan 6.111.24)

Same is said by Brahmānd Purān,

सीतायाश्च त्रिविधाशाः श्री भूनीलादिभेदतः ।
श्री भवेद् रुक्मिणी भूः स्यात् सत्यभामा वृढव्रता ॥
नीलास्याद् राधिका देवी सर्वलोकैक पूजिता ।

In short, Śrī Sītā manifests herself in three form Śrī, Bhu and Nila. By Śrī she becomes Rukmini by Bhu she becomes Satyabhama and by Nila she becomes Radha Rani Sarkār who is worshipped in all Lokas.

Gosvami Tulsidasa who is the incarnation of sage Vālmīki (-Bhavishyottar Purāṇa), says same thing in Śrī Rāmacharitmānas, that Śrī Rāma is like billions of Lord Vishṇu, infinite billions of Maa Durgā and billions of Lord Shiva.

रामु काम सत कोटि सुभग तन । दुर्गा कोटि अमित अरि मर्दन ॥
सक्र कोटि सत सरिस बिलासा । नभ सत कोटि अमित अवकासा ॥

सारद कोटि अमित चतुराई । बिधि सत कोटि सृष्टि निपुनाई ॥
बिष्नु कोटि सम पालन कर्ता । रुद्र कोटि सत सम संहर्ता ॥

(ŚrīRāmacaritamānasa 7.92.3/5)

Śrī Rāma's body possesses the charm of a myriad Cupids. He is as inexorable in crushing the enemy as countless millions of Durgās. He enjoys the luxury of a myriad Indra-s and is immeasurable in expanse as a myriad firmaments. He is as sharp as countless millions of Saraswatis-s and possesses the creative skill of a myriad Brahmā-s. Again, He is as good a preserver as billions of Vishṇu-s and as thorough a destroyer as billions of Rudra-s.

Incomparable as Śrī Rāma is, He has no compeer. Śrī Rāma alone is Śrī Rāma's peer - so declare the Vedas - even as the sun really suffers diminution by being likened to a myriad glow-worms.

And so Śrī Krishnā also a manifestation of Śrī Rāma,

यो रामः कृष्णतामेत्य सार्वात्म्यं प्राप्य लीलया । अतोषयद्देव्मौनिपटलं तं नतोऽस्म्यहम्।।

(Atharvavedā Shrüti Krishnōpanishad 1.1)

That Śrī Rāma, who transformed himself (incarnated) as Krishnā, attained Sarvaatmakta (सार्वभौमिकता) by his very lilā (divine exploits, pastimes); and thus deities-sages-masses were completely satisfied on this earth. I make prostration before that same Śrī Rāma.

Not only Śrī Rāma but his Mantra/ Name is also Paratpār as said by Vedas,

गाणपत्येषु शैवेषु शाक्तसौरेष्वभीष्टदः ।

वैष्णवेष्वपि सर्वेषु राममन्त्रः फलाधिकः॥

गाणपत्यादि मन्त्रेषु कोटिकोटिगुणाधिकः ।

मन्त्रस्तेष्वप्यनायास फलदोऽयं षडक्षरः ॥

(Atharvavedā Shrüti Rama uttartapini 5.6-7)

Among all the mantras of Lord Ganesha, Lord Shiva, Goddess Durga, Lord Surya and in all vaishnav mantra, the mantras dedicated to Shri Rama bestow greater fruits. And This Mantra-Raja of Bhagavan Shri Rama easily bestows Billions and Billions times the fruits of all the mantras dedicated to Lord Ganesha, Shiva, Durga, Surya and Vishnu. Such is the supreme glory of Mantra - Raj !

As said in Pulatsya Samhita,

सावित्री ब्रह्मणा सार्द्ध लक्ष्मीर्नारायणेन च ।

शंभुना राम रामेति पार्वती जपति स्फुटम् ।।

Srímati savitri with Śrī Brahma, mata lakshmi with Śrī Hāri Nāräyana, Śrī Shambhu with Maa Parvati constantly chants “Ram”.

As cleared by Srímad Goswami Tulsidas ji Maharaj in Rāmcharit Mānas that,

कहौं कहाँ लगि नाम बड़ाई।

रामु न सकहिं नाम गुन गाई॥

How far can I praise the name, even Rām cannot sing the virtues of his name.

This chaupāai is exact translation of Vashistha Tantra,

The strength of the name of Sri Raghavā has been cleared more in Vashistha Tantra;

रामनाम परा ये च रामनार्थचिंतकाः ।

तेषां पादरजस्पर्शात्पावनं भुवनत्रयम् ॥

कृष्णनारायणादीनि नामानि जपतो निशम् ।

सहस्‌‍‌त्रजन्मभी राम नाम्नि स्नेहो भवत्युत ॥

राम एवाभिजानाति रामनाम फलं हृदि ।

प्रवक्तुं नैव शक्नोति ब्रह्मादीनां तु का कथा ॥

Those who are ready to chant the name of Shri Ram and are the ones who think about the meaning of the name. All the three worlds are purified by their lotus feet. There are as many names of Lord Vishnu like Lord Krishna, Narayan etc. So after chanting these names for thousands of Births one get love in the name Rām. Only one Shri Ram knows the fruits of his name in his heart but cannot say it. Because the Glory of his name is very big even his can't say that what to talk about Brahma and all.

मंत्र परम लघु जासु बस बिधि हरि हर सुर सर्ब।

महामत्त गजराज कहुँ बस कर अंकुस खर्ब ॥

(śrīrāmacaritamānasa bālakānda, dohā 256)

"The supreme sacred Mantra (the seed mantra Raam), indeed, is very small, although it has under its sway Brahm, Hari, Hara and all other gods. A tiny goad governs the mightiest and most furious elephant."

From the name of Śrī Rāma everything has came into existence that want Vedas has says. As his name is Superior and originator od everyone same like his Dhaam/ loka is also originator of different Lokas as mentioned in Vedas and Purān;

Śrī Ayōdhyā-Puri (Sāketa-Loka) is the original source of all Vaikuntha, where the Brahm in his own original form of Śrī Rāma is present with Śrī Śrī Sītā Jī.

ॐ याऽयोध्या सा सर्वबैकुण्ठानामेव मूलाधारा प्रकृतेः परा तत्सद् ब्रह्ममयी विरजोत्तरा दिव्यरत्नकोशाढ्या तस्या नित्यमेव श्रीसीतारामयोर्विहारस्थलमस्ति।।

Atharvavedā Shrüti Ram Rahashya Upnishad Uttarkhañd)

Ayodhya, which is beyond nature, true form, Brahmamayi, is also the foundation of all the Vaikunth worlds. Rivers like Virja emerge in its north. And Shri Sitaram ji's place of residence is always present in the Kosh (Mandap) decorated with divine gems.

In Padma puran it been clearly mentioned that Mathura etc Puris are servent of Śrī Ayodhyā Ji,

मथुराद्याः पुरी सर्वा अयोध्यापुरदासिकाः ।
अयोध्यामेव सेवन्ते प्रलयेऽप्रलयेऽपि वा ॥

(Padma Puran)

Mathura etc. all Purias are maidservants of Śrī Ayodhyā Puri. These Puris serve Ayodhyā ji with servility on both the occasions of doomsday and creation.

वैकुण्ठाः पंच विख्याताः क्षीराब्धिश्च रमाख्यकः ।

महाकारणवैकुण्ठौ पञ्चमो विरजापरः ॥

नित्यं दिव्यमनेकभोगविभवं वैकुण्ठरूपोत्तरं ।

सत्यानन्दचिदात्मकं स्वयम्भू मूलं त्वयोध्यापुरी ॥

Bhargav Puran khand 3 Ch. 2

In sort, Śrī Ayodhyā Maharani is the Origin of 5 kinds of Vāikuntha as stated above, around same shloka is found in Vedas also,

बाह्यान्तस्तारकाकारं व्योमपञ्चक विग्रहम् ।

राजयोगक संसिद्धि रामचन्द्रमुपास्महे ।।

(Shukla Yajurveda Mandal Brahmanopanishad 1.1)

Pachch Param Vyom [Chidakash] is called Pachch Vaikunth, its master is Shri Ram who is Tarak Brahmakhya Rajyogaik Siddhi Swaroop.

So from here it is clear that Naam, Guna, lila, Dham of Śrī Rāma can't be matched with anyone.

Śrī Rāma is the most superior than anyone but as all are the manifestation of this sweetest lord that why no body can't be down grade. As Sri Rama himself present in their heart. He is above all I repeat He is above all. No one can Match Śrī Rāma, Srimad Bhagavad Mahapuran and Vedas has clearly mentioned,

नेदं यशो रघुपतेः सुरयाच्ञयाऽऽत्त लीलातनोरधिकसाम्यविमुक्तधाम्नः।
रक्षोवध जलधिबन्धनमस्त्रपूगैः किं
तस्य शत्रुहनने कपयः सहायाः।।

(Śrīmad Bhagwat Mahapurana 9.11.20)

In short, Parikshit! There is no one like Lord Shri Raghuvar, then how can anyone be greater than him.

But believe me knowing all these things will go in vain if you not chanting the sweetest name Sitaram Sitaram.

So winding up with a line that I personally follow,

Knowing every siddhant every concept like a machine a will not take you to Sāket but chanting SītāRām SītāRām will, it can even make you memory card in next birth

So please stop the Mind's Drama Just Chant Hare Rama

Hāri Bol Hāri Bol

Hail to Priya Pritam Sarkar ❤️

Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya

Answer (score 2):

श्रीरामचन्द्र चरणौ शरणं प्रपद्ये।
Salutations to the feet of Bhagwan Shri Ramchandra.

This post will be purely based on shlokas of hanumat samhita.

**ब्रह्मा विष्णु महेशाद्या यस्य अंशा लोक साधकाः।
तं रामं सच्चिदानन्द नित्यं रास ईश्वरं भजे।।**

~ I adore that Ramchandra always, Who is a form of sat-chit-Anans, Expert in Raas leela and Whose portions are Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesvara.

**आज्ञया देवदेवस्य श्रीरामस्य महात्मनः।
सन्त्यवतारा बहवः अंश कला विभुतयाः।।**

With the order of mahatma devadhidev bhagwan shri Ramchandra, there had been many kala avtar, vibhuti avtar and ansh avtar

**मत्स्य कुर्म वराहश्च तथा नृसिंह वामनैः।
भार्गवो बलिकंसारी बौद्धकल्की विमिश्रितौ।
उपास्यमानं देवेशं देवानां प्रवरं विभुतम्।।**

Matsya, kurma, varah,narsimha, vaman, parshuram,krishna, balram, budha, kalki- these are main avtars of Bhagwan Shri Ramchandra

**बहवोवतारश्च सकला अंशविभुतयः।
रामो परात्पर साक्षात् भगवान् परमेश्वरः।।**

There had been so many ansha, kala, vibhuti avtars but shri Ram is the only supreme among all avtars and supreme personality of godhead and parmeshwar

**तुरीया जानकी प्रोक्ता तुरीयो रघुनन्दनः।
उभयोरंशजाः सर्वे च अवतारह्यसंख्यकाः॥**

As janaknandini maa sita is mool form so is raghunandan sarkar (aka shri Ramchandra). From them (sita ram), all avtars have originated.

**सर्वेषामवताराणाम् अवतारी रघूत्तमः।
श्रुतं दृष्टं मया सर्व चिरायजीवानन्मुने॥**

Hanuman ji says to maharishi agastya:-
Among all avtars, shri Ram is supreme personality of godhead (sarv avtari swaym bhagwan). As a chiranjivi, I have seen and heard all of this.